# How to make a window with no major vertical scroll bars

Tags: css, height

I am using the jQuery library Nanoscroller to get the content div to scroll if it has a lot of content in there, and it does this fine. However, the problem I have is that the browser window still has a major scroll button on it (ie. the regular one on the right of a page).

What I want is for the header to be at the top, the footer to be at the bottom, and for the content to always take up whatever available height is remaining in the browser window. Such that the only scroll buttons will be the Nanoscroller ones within the content div. What I want is something like this:

[image: Example]
The code I am using is this:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        header
    </div>

    <div id="mycontent" class="nano">
        <div class="content">
            my content
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

With this css:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#container {
    margin: 0;
}

#header {
    text-align:center;
    background: #777;
    color:#fff;
    height:50px;
}

#mycontent {
    background-color:red;
}

#footer {
    background-color:blue;
        clear:both;
        height: 50px;
}
```

I have tried various combinations of making the position fixed for the header and footer, the height set to 100% of the mycontent div, ect and still no joy. I always seem to end up with a little bit too much of the page, such that I'm getting that major scroll bar appearing.

Any thoughts are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: fixed` instead:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
}

body {
    overflow-y: hidden;

#mycontent {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that just cuts off anything overflowing the page, so my footer is actually hidden now.